Generate figure showing curvature of 2d surface
I would like to generate figures showing lines (geodesics) on constant-curvature 2d surfaces (spherical, flat Euclidean, hyperboloid), in order to illustrate by analogy the curvature of the Universe.
Basically, I would like to make figures like this, but with details under my own control:

(This is actually a bad example since the lines on the hyperboloid don’t seem correctly curved!)
Any tips on where to begin, or prior art?

Not lines of constant curvature, but geodesics (“straight lines”) on surfaces that have constant curvature.

The second hyperbolic surface is not a constant negative curvature surface although its curvature is negative.

The pictures from Wiki is wrong,
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:End_of_universe.jpg,  the second geodesic triangle should be concave instead of convex.

@cvgmt Exactly. This is why I want to be able to adjust this myself...

Edit-2

we can move the points in the u-v domain to change the points in surface and see the geodesic curves.

Clear["Global`*"];
n = 2;
x = {u, v};
r@{u_, v_} := {u, v, (u + v)*(u - v)/4};
surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[r@{u, v}], {u, -3.5, 3.5}, {v, -3.5, 3.5},
    MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #5 &}, Mesh -> {20, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.8], Black}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}];
frame[i_] := Derivative[UnitVector[n, i]][r][x];
g = Table[Dot[frame[i], frame[j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
invg = Inverse[g];
Γ[i_, j_][k_] := 
  1/2 Sum[invg[[
       k, μ]] (D[g[[i, μ]], x[[j]]] + 
        D[g[[j, μ]], x[[i]]] - D[g[[i, j]], x[[μ]]]), {μ, 
      1, n}] // Simplify;
eqns = {Table[
    x[[k]]''[s] + 
      Sum[(Γ[i, j][k] /. 
          Table[x[[α]] -> x[[α]][s], {α, 1, n}])*
        x[[i]]'[s]*x[[j]]'[s], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] == 0, {k, 1, n}],
    Through@x[0] == {u0, v0}, 
   Through@(Derivative[1] /@ x)[0] == AngleVector[θ]};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, 
   x, {s, 0, L}, {u0, v0, θ, L}];
exp[{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}] := {dir, length} /. 
   NMinimize[{(Indexed[sol[u1, v1, dir, length], 1]@length - 
          u2)^2 + (Indexed[sol[u1, v1, dir, length], 2]@length - 
          v2)^2}, {dir, length}][[2]];
line[{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}] := Module[{dir, length},
   {dir, length} = exp[{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}];
   ParametricPlot3D[
    r@Through@sol[u1, v1, dir, length]@s, {s, 0, length}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]];
Manipulate[{ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, -3.5, 3.5}, {v, -3.5, 3.5}, 
   Mesh -> {5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow], 
   Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Small], 
  Show[surface, line[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]], line[pt[[2]], pt[[3]]], 
   line[pt[[3]], pt[[1]]], 
   Graphics3D[{PointSize@Large, Yellow, Ball[r@pt[[1]], .1], Cyan, 
     Ball[r@pt[[2]], .1], Green, Ball[r@pt[[3]], .1]}], 
   ImageSize -> Medium, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, BoxRatios -> Automatic,
    Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False]}, {{pt, {{.2, .5}, {.1, 2.2}, {2.5, 3.1}}}, Locator,
   TrackingFunction -> 
   Function[pos, 
    pt = RegionNearest[Rectangle[{-3.5, -3.5}, {3.5, 3.5}]]@pos], 
  Appearance -> {Graphics[{Yellow, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
      Point[{0, 0}]}], 
    Graphics[{Cyan, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}], 
    Graphics[{Green, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}]}}]




For sphere.

Clear["Global`*"];
n = 2;
x = {u, v};
r@{u_, v_} := FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, u, v}] // Evaluate;
surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[r@{u, v}], {u, 0, π}, {v, 0, 2  π}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.8], Black}, Mesh -> {20, 40}, 
   Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}];
frame[i_] := Derivative[UnitVector[n, i]][r][x];
g = Table[Dot[frame[i], frame[j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
invg = Inverse[g];
Γ[i_, j_][k_] := 
  1/2  Sum[
     invg[[k, μ]]  (D[g[[i, μ]], x[[j]]] + 
        D[g[[j, μ]], x[[i]]] - D[g[[i, j]], x[[μ]]]), {μ, 
      1, n}] // Simplify;
eqns = {Table[
    x[[k]]''[s] + 
      Sum[(Γ[i, j][k] /. 
          Table[x[[α]] -> x[[α]][s], {α, 1, n}])*
        x[[i]]'[s]*x[[j]]'[s], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] == 0, {k, 1, n}],
    Through@x[0] == {u0, v0}, 
   Through@(Derivative[1] /@ x)[0] == AngleVector[θ]};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, 
   x, {s, 0, L}, {u0, v0, θ, L}];
exp[{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}] := {dir, length} /. 
   NMinimize[{(Indexed[sol[u1, v1, dir, length], 1]@length - 
          u2)^2 + (Indexed[sol[u1, v1, dir, length], 2]@length - 
          v2)^2}, {dir, length}][[2]];
line[{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}] := 
  Module[{dir, length}, {dir, length} = exp[{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}];
   ParametricPlot3D[
    r@Through@sol[u1, v1, dir, length]@s, {s, 0, length}, 
    PlotStyle -> Red]];
Manipulate[{ParametricPlot[{u, v}, {u, 0, π}, {v, 0, 2 π}, 
   Mesh -> {5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.1, Lighter@Yellow], 
   Frame -> False, ImageSize -> Small], 
  Show[surface, line[pt[[1]], pt[[2]]], line[pt[[2]], pt[[3]]], 
   line[pt[[3]], pt[[1]]], 
   Graphics3D[{PointSize@Large, Yellow, Ball[r@pt[[1]], .05], Cyan, 
     Ball[r@pt[[2]], .05], Green, Ball[r@pt[[3]], .05]}], 
   ImageSize -> Medium, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic, Boxed -> False, 
   Axes -> False]}, {{pt, {{0.5, 1.1}, {1.5, .2}, {1.6, 1.5}}}, 
  Locator, 
  TrackingFunction -> 
   Function[pos, 
    pt = RegionNearest[Rectangle[{0, 0}, {π, 2 π}]]@pos], 
  Appearance -> {Graphics[{Yellow, AbsolutePointSize[10], 
      Point[{0, 0}]}], 
    Graphics[{Cyan, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}], 
    Graphics[{Green, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[{0, 0}]}]}}]


Edit-1

For any two points {u1,v1} and {u2,v2}, we defind a transformation exp to get the dir and length which translate the {u1,v1} to {u2,v2} along the geodesic curve.

Clear["Global`*"];
n = 2;
x = {u, v};
r@{u_, v_} := {u, v, u*v};
(* r@{u_,v_}:={u,v,0}; *)
domain = RegularPolygon[{3.5, π/2}, 4];
surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[r@{u, v}], {u, v} ∈ domain, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> {20, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.8], Black}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}];
frame[i_] := Derivative[UnitVector[n, i]][r][x];
g = Table[Dot[frame[i], frame[j]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
invg = Inverse[g];
Γ[i_, j_][k_] := 
  1/2 Sum[invg[[
       k, μ]] (D[g[[i, μ]], x[[j]]] + 
        D[g[[j, μ]], x[[i]]] - D[g[[i, j]], x[[μ]]]), {μ, 
      1, n}] // Simplify;
eqn = {Table[
    x[[k]]''[s] + 
      Sum[(Γ[i, j][k] /. 
          Table[x[[α]] -> x[[α]][s], {α, 1, n}])*
        x[[i]]'[s]*x[[j]]'[s], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] == 0, {k, 1, n}],
    Through@x[0] == {u0, v0}, 
   Through@(Derivative[1] /@ x)[0] == AngleVector[θ]};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqn, x, {s, 0, L}, {u0, v0, θ, L}];
exp[{u1_, v1_}, {u2_, v2_}] := {dir, length} /. 
   NMinimize[{(Indexed[sol[u1, v1, dir, length], 1]@length - 
          u2)^2 + (Indexed[sol[u1, v1, dir, length], 2]@length - 
          v2)^2}, {dir, length}][[2]];
{u1, v1} = {0.56, -1.95};
{u2, v2} = {-2.54, 0.3};
{u3, v3} = {2.5, 0.1};
{dir1, length1} = exp[{u1, v1}, {u2, v2}];
{dir2, length2} = exp[{u2, v2}, {u3, v3}];
{dir3, length3} = exp[{u3, v3}, {u1, v1}];
Show[surface, 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r@Through@sol[u1, v1, dir1, length1]@s, {s, 0, length1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r@Through@sol[u2, v2, dir2, length2]@s, {s, 0, length2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r@Through@sol[u3, v3, dir3, length3]@s, {s, 0, length3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]



For the sphere,  we change some settings.

r@{u_, v_} := FromSphericalCoordinates[{1, u, v}] // Evaluate;

surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[r@{u, v}], {u, 0, π}, {v, 0, 2 π},
    PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.8], Black}, Mesh -> {20,40}, 
   Method -> {"BoundaryOffset" -> False}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}, 
   BoundaryStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}];

{u1, v1} = {0.5, 1.1};
{u2, v2} = {1.5, .2};
{u3, v3} = {1.6, 1.5};


Original

Γ[i_, j_][k_] is the Christoffel symbols.
eqn is the geodesic equations.
We need to find an automatic way to get the valutes dir3 = 1.3; length3 = 3.2; for the point {u1,v1}, maybe  need to use the Shooting Method updated later.

Clear["Global`*"];
n = 2;
x = {u, v};
r@{u_, v_} := {u, v, u*v};
surface = 
  ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[r@{u, v}], {u, v} ∈ 
    RegularPolygon[{3, π/2}, 4], 
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> {20, 20}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.8], Black}, 
   MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}];
frame = Table[D[r[x], x[[i]]], {i, 1, n}];
g = Table[Dot[frame[[i]], frame[[j]]], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}];
invg = Inverse[g];
Γ[i_, j_][k_] := 
  1/2 Sum[invg[[
       k, μ]] (D[g[[i, μ]], x[[j]]] + 
        D[g[[j, μ]], x[[i]]] - D[g[[i, j]], x[[μ]]]), {μ, 
      1, n}] // Simplify;
eqn = {Table[
    x[[k]]''[s] + 
      Sum[(Γ[i, j][k] /. 
          Table[x[[α]] -> x[[α]][s], {α, 1, n}])*
        x[[i]]'[s]*x[[j]]'[s], {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}] == 0, {k, 1, n}],
    Through@x[0] == {u0, v0}, 
   Through@(Derivative[1] /@ x)[0] == AngleVector[θ]};
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[eqn, x, {s, 0, L}, {u0, v0, θ, L}];
{u0, v0} = {.1, 1.2};
dir1 = 4.8;
dir2 = 5.3;
length1 = 3.5;
length2 = 2.5;
{u1, v1} = Through@sol[u0, v0, dir1, length1]@length1;
{u2, v2} = Through@sol[u0, v0, dir2, length2]@length2;
dir3 = 1.3;
length3 = 3.2;
Show[surface, 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r@Through@sol[u0, v0, dir1, length1]@s, {s, 0, length1}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r@Through@sol[u0, v0, dir2, length2]@s, {s, 0, length2}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  r@Through@sol[u1, v1, dir3, length3]@s, {s, 0, length3}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Graphics3D[{Green, Ball[r@{u1, v1}, .15], Ball[r@{u2, v2}, .15]}], 
 Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, ViewPoint -> {0.45, -2.5, 2.3}]




To test the third and first cases, we can set

r@{u_, v_} := {u, v, 0};
r@{u_, v_} := FromSphericalCoordinates[{1,u,v}] // Evaluate;

respectly.

Beautiful. Probably "the" answer, but let me also try to solve the problem of where to place the points...

If just replace the second case "r@{u_, v_}", the result is wrong.

@babyK See the updated.  For the sphere, we can set {u1, v1} = {0.56, 1.95}; {u2, v2} = {1.54, 1.3}; {u3, v3} = {2.5, 0.1};   and surface =    ParametricPlot3D[    Evaluate[r@{u, v}], {u, v} ∈      RegularPolygon[{2 π, π/2}, 4],     MeshFunctions -> {#1 + #2 &, #1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> {20, 20},     PlotStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.8], Black},     MeshStyle -> Directive@{Opacity[.9], White}];

uv = RandomPoint[RegularPolygon[{3.5, π/2}, 4], 4]; {dirs, lengths} = Transpose[exp @@@ Partition[uv, 2, 1, 1]]; {U, V} = Transpose[uv]; k = Length@uv; Show[surface,   Table[ParametricPlot3D[    r@Through@sol[U[[i]], V[[i]], dirs[[i]], lengths[[i]]]@s, {s, 0,      lengths[[i]]}, PlotStyle -> Red], {i, 1, k}], Boxed -> False,   Axes -> False]

V2 looks great, although I'm going to try to adjust the positions of the triangles. One comment: the MeshFunction for the sphere is incorrect (or at least it's not the usual lon-lat grid...) -- I think the correct one should have something like ArcTan[#1, #2] in the second position, but that doesn't quite work (different "north pole" than the other grid. Trying to figure it out...

I think the more standard grid in this case is  MeshFunctions->{#3, ArcTan[#1, #2]} (i.e., {z, ArcTan[y/x]}).

@AndrewJaffe For sphere,simplely remove the Meshfunctions. I have no computer in hands happens.

This method is not universal for all three cases like @cvgmt's answer because for some reason NDSolve was not able to solve my differential equations for a sphere.
I also think that square is a better choice than equilateral triangle since right angle is easier to recognize by sight than 60 degree angle. But RegularPolygon[4] can be replaced with RegularPolygon[3] if one prefers.
I concentrated on two things - that also the mesh consist of geodesic lines and that the square is of the same width in all three cases. Its width is equal to 8 mesh squares.
I also wanted to make an animation of how plane deforms to sphere and back to plane and then to hyperbolic paraboloid, i.e. morphing between the three images below but it seems to be too complicated.
eq = {x''[t] == 0, y''[t] == 0};

so = NDSolve[{eq, {x[0], y[0]} == #1, {x[1], y[1]} == #2}, {x, y}, {t,
       0, 1}] & @@@ 
   Subsets[PolygonCoordinates@RegularPolygon[4]*Sqrt[2]/2, {2}];

Show[ContourPlot3D[z == 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ContourStyle -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{x[t], y[t], 0} /. #} & /@ so // Evaluate, {t, 0, 
   1}], ViewPoint -> Top]



gc := ((fu |-> 
       Dot[{-1, 1} fu, {Sin[(-1 + f) ArcCos[#1 . #2]], 
         Sin[f ArcCos[#1 . #2]]}]) /@ Transpose[{##}])/(Sqrt[
    1 - (#1 . #2)^2]) &

Show[ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[u] Sin[v], Cos[v], -Sin[u] Sin[v]}, {u, Pi,
    2 Pi}, {v, 0, Pi}, MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, ArcTan[#3, #2] &}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[0.2], PlotStyle -> Black, Boxed -> False,
   Axes -> False], 
 ParametricPlot3D[
  gc @@@ Subsets[
     PolygonCoordinates@RegularPolygon[4]*
       Sqrt[6]/3 /. {x_, y_} :> {x, y, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {2}] // 
   Evaluate, {f, 0, 1}], ViewPoint -> Top]



(*calculating mesh points*)

al = ArcLength[{-1, t, 1 - t^2}, {t, -1, 1}];
qe = Table[
   FindRoot[
    ArcLength[{-1, t, 1 - t^2}, {t, -1, q}] == k al/8, {q, 0}], {k, 0,
     8}];
qm = ({-1, q}) /. # & /@ qe;

me1 = Transpose[{qm, {-1, 1}*# & /@ qm}];
me2 = Transpose[{Reverse /@ qm, {1, -1}*# & /@ (Reverse /@ qm)}];
me3 = Transpose[{Reverse[#], #}] &@Rest@Most@me1[[All, 1]];
me4 = Transpose[{Reverse[#], #}] &@Rest@Most@me2[[All, 1]];
me5 = Transpose[{Reverse[#], #}] &@
   Rest@Most@({-1, 1}*# & /@ me1[[All, 1]]);
me6 = Transpose[{Reverse[#], #}] &@
   Rest@Most@({1, -1}*# & /@ me2[[All, 1]]);
me = Join[me1, me2, me3, me4, me5, me6];

(* hyperbolic paraboloid*)

eq = {x''[t] == (
    4 x[t] (-x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2))/(
    1 + 4 x[t]^2 + 4 y[t]^2), y''[t] == (
    4 y[t] (x'[t]^2 - y'[t]^2))/(
    1 + 4 x[t]^2 + 4 y[t]^2)};

so = NDSolve[{eq, {x[0], y[0]} == #1, {x[1], y[1]} == #2}, {x, y}, {t,
       0, 1}] & @@@ 
   Subsets[PolygonCoordinates@RegularPolygon[1, 4] Sqrt[2], {2}];

mso = NDSolve[{eq, {x[0], y[0]} == #1, {x[1], y[1]} == #2}, {x, 
      y}, {t, 0, 1}] & @@@ me;


Show[ContourPlot3D[z == x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
   ContourStyle -> Black, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, 
  Mesh -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{x[t], y[t], x[t]^2 - y[t]^2} /. #} & /@ mso // 
   Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thin, GrayLevel[0.2]]],
  ParametricPlot3D[{{x[t], y[t], x[t]^2 - y[t]^2} /. #} & /@ so // 
   Evaluate, {t, 0, 1}], ViewPoint -> Top]






